# 'post' table usability - error when installing .ttf font on mac

Tags: font, font-book

So, when i try to install a .ttf font on my mac it stops installing and gives me this message

1 serious error was found. Do not use this font file.

and in the list there is, 'post' table usability , flagged as red

I'm really curious.. - what does the error actually wanna tell me? - what could happen if i use, or perhaps just install it? - and what does 'post' mean in that list of all things?

Is it a bug, is it serious, or just nonsense!?

Thank you!

And no, i'm not working for Apple!!

Comment: In 20 years I don’t think I ever seen a font book warning that resulted in anything more serious than the font just not working as expected.

Comment: i once had to re-install the whole font stuff so i'm still a bit burnt from that

Comment: Some info on the post table  https://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=IWS-Chapter08#05931f9d

Comment: Thanks! so it's an adobe thing, did i get that right..
or if it's not provided adobe will might not accept it or the program might crash if you try _italic_ or some crap??

Comment: More info:   https://developer.apple.com/fonts/TrueType-Reference-Manual/RM06/Chap6post.html